# making list of list of a row while parsing the file

Tags: python-3.x

making list of list of a row while parsing the file  Apart from the first field, all the other fields are either numbers (so converted using float(), or empty, which can be translated to the Python object None

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think you're asking how to parse a file and read it into some python variables.  Maybe specify an example of the file you're trying to parse and what type of variable you'd like to input it into?

Comment: well my task is to read a file and turn its rows into list of lists after that the data I will get will be of the form [['Argentina,12,23,45,6667,87],['Argentina,12,23,45,6667,87],['Argentina,12,23,45,6667,87].....] but with different values and I have to compute mean median on each of the column except the first one because its the string after finding out the maximum and minimum values from each column and normalize those max values to 1 and minimum to 0.any help would be appreciated